# Convert mySQL partition query to mySQL 5.7 Compatible query where there are two sums in one query

Tags: mysql, partition

I have the following query that works perfectly in mysql 8:

```
SELECT 
       J.JobID, Month(WH.DateStart) as MonthCharged, Year(WH.DateStart) as YearCharged, sum(WH.Duration) as HoursWorkedInMonth, sum(WH.Duration) over (partition by J.JobID order by Month(WH.DateStart), Year(WH.DateStart)) as CumulativeJobHoursWorked
    FROM
        tblJob J
    JOIN tblTask T ON CONCAT('JOB-', RIGHT(YEAR(J.DateCreated), 2), '-', LPAD(J.JobID, 4, '0')) = T.SourceID
    LEFT JOIN xrefTasktoEmployee XT ON T.TaskID = XT.TaskID
    LEFT JOIN tblWorkHistory WH ON XT.WorkHistoryID = WH.WorkHistoryID
    LEFT JOIN tblRates R ON XT.rateID = R.RateID
Where WH.Duration is not NULL
Group by  J.JobID, Month(WH.DateStart), Year(WH.DateStart)
```

And it produces the following results:

| Job ID | Month Charged | Year Charged | HoursWorkedInMonth | CumulativeJobHoursWorked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2021 | 23.98 | 23.98 |
| 1 | 4 | 2021 | 24.98 | 47.96 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021 | 8 | 8 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021 | 8 | 8 |
| 4 | 3 | 2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2021 | 10 | 10 |

Notice how I am summing the hours worked in the month & year for a particular job, then I need the cumulative for that Job for the year.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this in MySQL 5.7 by using variables.  Does anyone have any insights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally got to work:

```
SELECT 
       J.JobID, Month(WH.DateStart) as MonthCharged, Year(WH.DateStart) as YearCharged, sum(WH.Duration) as HoursWorkedInMonth, (SELECT 
      sum(WH2.Duration)
    FROM
        tblJob J2
    JOIN tblTask T2 ON CONCAT('JOB-', RIGHT(YEAR(J2.DateCreated), 2), '-', LPAD(J2.JobID, 4, '0')) = T2.SourceID
    LEFT JOIN xrefTasktoEmployee XT2 ON T2.TaskID = XT2.TaskID
    LEFT JOIN tblWorkHistory WH2 ON XT2.WorkHistoryID = WH2.WorkHistoryID 
Where WH2.Duration is not NULL and J2.JobID = J.JobID and DATE_FORMAT(WH2.DateStart, '%m-%Y') <= DATE_FORMAT(WH.DateStart, '%m-%Y')) as CumulativeJobHoursWorked
    FROM
        tblJob J
    JOIN tblTask T ON CONCAT('JOB-', RIGHT(YEAR(J.DateCreated), 2), '-', LPAD(J.JobID, 4, '0')) = T.SourceID
    LEFT JOIN xrefTasktoEmployee XT ON T.TaskID = XT.TaskID
    LEFT JOIN tblWorkHistory WH ON XT.WorkHistoryID = WH.WorkHistoryID
Where WH.Duration is not NULL
Group by  J.JobID, Month(WH.DateStart), Year(WH.DateStart)
```